# TinyMCE change language dynamically with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm building an online editor where the language is set by the user settings that can be change dynamically with AJAX (page does not reload), so I init the tinyMCE object the first time correctly but after the user try to init it again, the text inside the editor controls has incorrect values ("advanced.bold" instead of "Bold", advanced.italic_desc instead of "Italic", etc), but the plugin popups are in the correct language!

Basically my code just do the init method each time the user changes the language in their preferences...

```
initMCE: function(lang) {
    tinyMCE.init({  
        language : lang,
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        relative_urls : false,
        editor_selector : "tinymce",
        plugins : "emotions,spellchecker,advhr,insertdatetime,preview,media,inlinepopups,xhtmlxtras",

        // Theme options - button# indicated the row# only
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "fontselect,fontsizeselect,bold,italic,underline,forecolor,|,bullist,numlist,|,blockquote,|,image,|,link,unlink,|,code,spellchecker",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",      
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "right",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        content_css : "../_style/_css/style.css",
        inline_styles : false
    });
}
```

Any ideas of how to do it or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle or in this case (better) js fiddle for this?

Comment: Ok, [HERE](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/jYbaab) it is although there aren't lang packs in the tinymce fiddle so each time you change the lang from 'en' to 'es' you can't see the translated texts neither in the editor nor in the plugin popups (you see the incorrect values I talk about in my question instead):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this as bug on their site and they told me to use a workaround while they fix it (seems the load lang call is just running one time instead inside the init). Using this line after the init, the language change works fine:

```
tinyMCE.ThemeManager.requireLangPack(THEME_IN_USE);
```

Check [this fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/nYbaab/2) to see it working

Comment: Eng button works once. Spa button does not work at all. Have they fixed the bug you reported since?

Comment: Not sure tbh, I haven't used the plugin in a while, sry :/

Answer (score 0):

I created a [fiddle fork](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/nYbaab/1), trying to make it work and thought that you might need to shutdown your former instance correctly. The language did not change correctly - you might want to report a bugfix for this [here](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_bugs.php).

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what happens, the plugins popup are ok but not the editor buttons. Will try to report as a bug, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
 function init(lang) {  
        //language_url: lang === 'en' ? null : 'url to es file',
        options.language = lang;
        tinymce.remove(editor);
        tinymce.init(options);
        tinymce.execCommand('mceRepaint');
      }
```

This fiddle works for me, note the comments in line 31:

https://jsfiddle.net/antd3tsf/19/